# Why is the last line not being scanned

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to scan some lines of number. The lines with single number `num` represent how many rows there will be for the 2d array, and the next `num` lines will consist of 2 numbers and they should be recorded in the array called `townCord`.

An example input looks like this:

```
4
1 2
2 1
1 1
2 2
3
3 1
2 2
1 3
```

The last line, 1 3, is not in the 2d array though. I think the reason is because I split by the pattern " ". I wonder how I can fix this bug and record all of them in the array? Thanks in advance

```java
public static boolean checkWin(int x1,int y1, int x2, int y2){
        if(y1==y2){
            return false;
        } else{
            if(Math.toDegrees(Math.atan((Math.abs((double)(y1-y2)))/(Math.abs((double)(x1-x2)))))==45){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            int num = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
            int townCord[][] = new int[num][2];

            for (int i = 0; i < townCord.length; i++) {
                if(sc.hasNext()){
                    String[] line = sc.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
                    for (int j = 0; j < line.length; j++) {
                        townCord[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(line[j]);
                    }
                }else{
                    break;
                }
            }
            double overallCount = 0;
            double winCount = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i<num;i++){
                for(int j = 0;j<num;j++){
                    overallCount++;
                    if(checkWin(townCord[i][0],townCord[i][1],townCord[j][0],townCord[j][1])){
                        winCount++;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(winCount/overallCount);
        }
        sc.close();
}
```

EDIT: I think this is not working properly, because unless I hit enter after entering these numbers, I do not get the correct result.
[image: output should be 2 numbers]

output should be 2 numbers, yet it only prints one. I think by hitting enter, I add an extra line after the last `1 3` input, which makes the code working. Without doing that I only get 0.25, one number.

The input must be fixed and I cannot add anything to it. If you try to directly copy&paste the whole input thingy, it probably won't work.

EDIT 2: I posted full code and hopefully I did not make any stupid mistakes on the part that's not relevant to the scanner

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Your code correctly inputs all values into the array when I run it.

Comment: "The last line, 1 3, is not in the 2d array though" what makes you think so? How do you *see* that it is not there? At what point of execution you are observing that behavior?

Comment: Same here I also ran your code and  1 3 is there in the 2d array

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I assume you hit enter after the last line? If I hit enter, it will work, but I don't think I am allowed to do so. I edited the question for more details

Comment: @Pshemo I have printing statements after the scanner completes the loop. The output should be 0.25 and 0.666, each representing a set of data's result, yet I only got 0.25, not the second set.

Comment: *"If I hit enter, it will work, but I don't think I am allowed to do so"* why? *That is how* user is supposed to send data to standard input stream (before hitting enter/return key he still has option to use backspace and correct his input).

Comment: You have to indicate to the stream that you're done writing. That can be done either with the Enter key (which flushes the line to stdin and lets the program read it) or with EOF (Ctrl+D on Linux systems; indicates the total end of the stream). Both of those work equally well for me. Without either of those, the text hasn't been sent to the input stream yet; that's a console issue that your program has no control over.

Comment: @Pshemo the input is fed through an online compiler, and I do not have control over whether there is EOF. For my question, the instruction stated that there will not be EOF.

Comment: I am little confused since image included in question suggests you are using IntelliJ IDE and I was thinking problem you are asking about is related to *that* environment. BUT even if I use Intellij I still am *not* able to reproduce your problem. For instance if I try to execute code like (added printing after providing array): https://ideone.com/nj0kci it is printing arrays without problem (IntelliJ demo): https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNBUV.png. So maybe problem you are trying to ask about is related to part of code represented as `//some operation and printing statements not relevant`...

Comment: @Pshemo thanks for your work. I am confused with why my output is different from yours too. I will post the whole program on here, but by now I think I have spent too much time on it, so I won't pursue further unless someone can provide answer

Comment: I was finally able to reproduce your problem. Mistake was on my part, since while copying data from your question I also copied area *after* last 3 which included line separators (so console could now assume that this line would be sent to System.in). Without that line-separator after last 3, console will simply wait for that `return`/`enter` key which confirms user input which prevents `if(sc.hasNext())` from moving farther as Scanner can't be sure if there will or will not be new element (maybe user will decide to *send* some data, or generate EOF sequence - like with CTRL+D).

Comment: @Pshemo I totally agree with you. I think that scanner was just waiting for more inputs. I did try to run the code without `if(sc.hasNext())`, but I think it halts regardless, because there is  `while (sc.hasNextLine()) `. I wonder how I can resolve this issue? Perhaps a new way to collect inputs from scanner?

Comment: "I think that scanner was just waiting for more inputs." to be more precise it is waiting until you actually *send* `1 3` to System.in by pressing `return/enter` key. Note that before that, console lets us edit/correct data user is writing. *Confirming* and *sending* user input to input stream happens after pressing return/enter key. That is how it works. Nothing to solve here... just press that enter/return key.